# Как очистить историю сообщений в телеграмм боте? telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно при вводе текста "очистить" удалять историю сообщений.
`message.id` не сохранилось.

Comment: Если вы эти сообщения не сохраняли куда-то то уже никак.

Answer (score 0):

В диалоге бот никак не сможет удалить сообщения пользователя (представьте, что ваш собеседник удаляет ваши же сообщения). А для группового чата нужно просто дать боту права администратора + разрешение на удаление сообщений.

С редактированием точно так же.

Comment: Эмм, так-то очень даже может. Только что даже проверил, обычного `bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)` достаточно, чтобы все ваши сообщения в лс с ботом уничтожались